# Не могу добавить ссылки в Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Я создал проект WPF и мне нужно подключить к нему библиотеки. При добавлении я нажимаю на "add reference" - "browse", но ничего не происходит. Окно выбора обновляется и все.

Искал в интернете - писали что нужно сменить версию Framework на .NET 4.0, но это не помогло

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на кнопку `Browse...` внизу вы нажимали?

Comment: Я же написал, что не работает.

Comment: «Не работает» — это как? Не появляется диалог? Диалог появляется, ссылку вы находите, но возникает ошибка при добавлении? Телепат у нас на форуме всего один, да и тот редко заходит.

Answer (score 1):

Поздно наверное отвечать, но я столкнулся с такой же проблемой - решилась она включением совместимости с XP и правами администратора (на 7-ке 64).